# Probability of no two of the marbles drawn have same color

Tags: probability

A bag contains 10 blue marbles ,20 black marbles , 30 red marbles.A marble is drawn from the bag, its colour recorded and it is put back in the bag. This process is repeated 3 times .The probability that no two of the Marbles drawn have the same color?

If 3 repeated events are independent then $\frac {10}{60}\times\frac {20}{60}\times\frac {30}{60}=\frac 1{36}$

But the answer is $\frac 1 6$. How do you get this?

Comment: The probability you have calculated is that the first marble is blue, the secind marble is black, and the last is red.  However, they don't have to be drawn in that order.

Comment: If i do 1-1/36 then this make it any sense?

Comment: What do you think $1-\frac 1 {36}$ means, probabilistically?

Comment: No 1 have same color

Comment: What you have calculated is the probability of seeing Blue-Black-Red.  But what about Black-Blue-Red?  What about Red-Blue-Black?  What other permutations do you have to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 colors, so you have $3!=6$ possible combinations of total outcomes.

Your calculation was almost correct, but you forgot to multiply by this number.

**Edit - to clear up confusion**

The question is asking you to pull a marble 3 times, and each time it needs to be a different color. You can do that in these ($3!=6$) ways:

- Blue, Black, Red
- Blue, Red, Black
- Black, Blue, Red
- Black, Red, Blue
- Red, Blue, Black
- Red, Black, Blue

As you stated, the probabilities of drawing marbles are:

- Blue = $\frac {10}{60}$
- Black = $\frac {20}{60}$
- Red= $\frac {30}{60}$

So let's look at order #1, Blue, Black, Red. You have a $\frac {10}{60}\times\frac {20}{60}\times\frac {30}{60}=\frac 1{36}$ chance of this happening. But since each of the 6 options above include the same variables, each of these options has the same probability of occuring. So you have $6$ events with $\frac 1 {36}$ probability of occurring. That means that the probability of *any* of these outcomes is $6\times\frac 1 {36}=\frac 1 6$

Comment: Ok but can you give me complete solution .because i am getting confuse

Comment: You almost had it yourself. Literally just put this step before you calculate the probabilities of drawing Blue/Black/Red, then your answer is $6(\frac 1 {36})=\frac 1 6$

Comment: Sorry  i m not getting. I want to find no 2 color should be same

Comment: Please give me more explanation

Comment: The only "rule" is that you have to draw a different colored marble each time. There's nothing saying that it has to be in a specific order (Blue then Black then Red, for example). Since there are $3!=6$ *different* orders in which you can draw them, you need to multiply the probability that you found by $6$ to account for that.

Comment: Yeah i got it . But my confusion is that these cases should also  be possible    Red red then red and blue blue blue or black black black, red red blue etc

Comment: Those can't be possible because then you're not meeting the criteria that the question is asking of you. What you just described is the probability of drawing *any marble* which is $1$. You have to throw out all cases that include the same color twice.

Comment: Yeah sorry . Thanks for correcting me

Comment: I'm updating the answer, btw, with a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First, you may pick blue-black-red. Arrangement of this colours is 3!. Total probability is Your answer * 3!. i.e 1/6.